# node array declaration

Tags: c++, 2-3-4-tree

I am trying to initialize a node array in the node class, they are private members:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    class Data
    {
    public:
        long data;
        Data(long dd)
        {
            data=dd;
        }
        void displaydata()
        {
            cout<<data <<"  "<<endl;
        }
    };
    class node
    {
//these are what i have changed
        const static int order=4;
        int numitems;
        node *parent;


    vector<node>childarray(order);
        vector<Data>itemarray(order-1);

    };
```

but unfortunately it does not compile, the errors are:

```
  1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\234_tree\234_tree\234_tree.cpp(26): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'order'
    1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\234_tree\234_tree\234_tree.cpp(27): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'order'
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

From the following java code.

```
class DataItem
{
public long dData; // one data item
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public DataItem(long dd) // constructor
{ dData = dd; }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
public void displayItem() // display item, format “/27”
{ System.out.print(“/”+dData); }
//--------------------------------------------------------------
} // end class DataItem
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class Node
{
private static final int ORDER = 4;
private int numItems;
private Node parent;
private Node childArray[] = new Node[ORDER];
private DataItem itemArray[] = new DataItem[ORDER-1];
// -------------------------------------------------------------
// connect child to this node
public void connectChild(int childNum, Node child)
{
childArray[childNum] = child;
if(child != null)
child.parent = this;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
// disconnect child from this node, return it
public Node disconnectChild(int childNum)
{
Node tempNode = childArray[childNum];
childArray[childNum] = null;
return tempNode;
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public Node getChild(int childNum)
{ return childArray[childNum]; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public Node getParent()
{ return parent; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isLeaf()
Java Code for a 2-3-4 Tree 479
LISTING 10.1 Continued
{ return (childArray[0]==null) ? true : false; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public int getNumItems()
{ return numItems; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public DataItem getItem(int index) // get DataItem at index
{ return itemArray[index]; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public boolean isFull()
{ return (numItems==ORDER-1) ? true : false; }
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public int findItem(long key) // return index of
{ // item (within node)
for(int j=0; j<ORDER-1; j++) // if found,
{ // otherwise,
if(itemArray[j] == null) // return -1
break;
else if(itemArray[j].dData == key)
return j;
}
return -1;
} // end findItem
// -------------------------------------------------------------
public int insertItem(DataItem newItem)
{
// assumes node is not full
numItems++; // will add new item
long newKey = newItem.dData; // key of new item
for(int j=ORDER-2; j>=0; j--) // start on right,
{ // examine items
if(itemArray[j] == null) // if item null,
continue; // go left one cell
else // not null,
{ // get its key
long itsKey = itemArray[j].dData;
if(newKey < itsKey) // if it’s bigger
itemArray[j+1] = itemArray[j]; // shift it right
else
{
itemArray[j+1] = newItem; // insert new item
```

Please help me to convert code easily, do I have to declare the order as public? I have tried but it does not work, I have also tried declaration of order outside of the class, like
    const int  node::order=4
but have had no success yet, what is the problem? I need  array which holds members, size should be order or 4. When I was reading book, author said what you need while writing java code in C++ from this book, it says pointer, so I have added pointer, but no success yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines

```
node *childarray[]=new node[order];
Data *itemarray[]=new Data[order-1];
```

are in error here. Beside that you can not assign like this in the class, you also have the declaration wrong. You are declaring e.g. `childarray` to be an array of pointers, but you are creating it as a simple array. Change declarations to

```
node *childarray;
Data *itemarray;
```

To actually do the allocation you have to do it in a constructor.

However, I really recommend you use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (or possibly [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)) instead.

**Edit:** Using `std::array`:

```
struct node
{
    static const int ORDER = 4;
    int numitems;
    node* parent;
    std::array<node*, ORDER> childarray;
    std::array<Data*, ORDER - 1> itemarray;

    node()
        : numitems{0},
          parent{nullptr},
          childarray{{nullptr}},
          itemarray{{nullptr}}
        { }
};
```

Now `childarray` and `itemarray` are arrays with `ORDER` and `ORDER - 1` (respectively) number of pointers, all initialized to `nullptr` (what `NULL` should now).

Comment: but how to change then code so that,it would be same as java code?i can post full code of java node declaration,it is not big

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili See my modified answer. The only way you can get closer to Java would be to use e.g. [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) instead of raw pointers.

Comment: can't i do it using vector?also when i need to check if something is not equal to NULL,i have to do if something is not equal nullptr?

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili `std::vector` is good if you want an array that can be added to runtime, or if your standard library doesn't yet have `std::array`. Also `nullptr` is compatible with `NULL`.

Comment: ok i wll choose std::array,but first   node constructor has syntax error

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili It does? If I define an empty `Data` structure it works fine for me. What error do you get?

Comment: syntax errors,like this 1>c:\users\dato\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\234_tree\234_tree\234_tree.cpp(32): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body

Comment: one question,if i  dont used pointers and do like in java,would it be efficient?

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili Well, you won't have to deal with pointers, which might be tough to handle if you come from a Java background. As for efficiency it's hard to tell before you try both ways and profile.